# explanation for binary tree code

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have found a code for a binary tree in Java which is:

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;
    Node curr;
    public void addNode(int n){
        Node temp=new Node(n);
        if (root==null){
            root=temp;
        }
        else{
            curr=root;
            while(curr!=null){
                System.out.println("current element "+curr.elem);
                if (temp.elem>curr.elem){
                    curr=curr.right;
                    if (curr==null){
                        System.out.println("added right branch element "+temp.elem);
                        root.der=temp;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    curr=curr.left;
                    if (curr==null){
                        root.left=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Node {
    int e;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Nodo (int n){
        e=n;
        left=null;
        right=null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Tree t=new Tree();
        t.addNode(5);
        t.addNode(10);
        t.addNode(20);
        t.addNode(50);   
    }
```

I have added some printing lines to see it inner working, but the problem I got is why the data that prints this code is:

```
current element 5
added right branch element 10
current element 5
current element 10
added right branch element 20
current element 5
current element 20
added right branch element 50
current element 5
current element 50
added right branch element 100
```

I mean why it jumps in the while loop and does not print the inside elements?. For example when inserting the number 50 I suppose it should print:

```
current element 5
current element 10
current element 20
```

but no going directly from 5 to 20, why is that? also the line that says:

root.der=temp or root.left=temp; does it mean that all the tree is treated like a big node every time I add a new node?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: somepeople think that is funny to put a minus one in one post and not even putting a comment or a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that algorithm is broken.  It's inserting the new nodes directly off the root node every time, erasing whatever was there before.

If you print your tree, you will find it only has a root node of 5, and off its right, a node of 100 (2 nodes total in the tree).